Vintage Cartoon - Dinosaur Cave River
I am trying to identify a cartoon I saw many years ago, where a group of people are rafting down a river in a prehistoric cave. There were dinosaurs on the shore. If I remember right, the river eventually turns into rapids. I don't believe this was Valley of the Dinosaurs or anything from Hanna-Barbera and it was definitely animated.

In roughly which year did you watch this?

Not animated but Land of the Lost features rafting, rapids, caves, and dinosaurs.

Dinosaurs appeared in lots of cartoon shows during the 1960s-70s. There was one about Huckleberry Finn, Tom Sawyer, and Becky Thatcher traveling on a raft, pursued by Injun Joe, and I believe that I recall an episode where they encountered a prehistoric land.

Do you remember the length? Loony Tunes length (a few minutes). Saturday morning cartoon length (half hour). Feature film length? Color or b&w? Was the cartoon focused on the people in the raft or on the world they were in?

There was a cartoon about Gulliver's adventures in Lilliput with an episode including a cave and dinosaurs, but I recall no raft from that one.
